# Choosing between JS Web and .NET Desktop UI

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, angular, user-interface

I'm currently looking for a technology to build a stock trading terminal. UI is going to be very complex and heavy. There is 2 possible options I'm considering:
-.NET Desktop App (WPF)
-Web App (Angular JS)

Is it possible to build such a complex UI with Angular? There is going to be a lot of charts, graphic tools and data visualization. It has to be very fast and responsive.

What are the pros and cons of choosing JS? I'm currently thinking about choosing desktop, but want to consider other options.

Comment: Modern web applications actually made quite a big progress in terms of perfomance, so nowadays it's usually not a problem. I personally developed quite a lot of WPF applications, and last years I both ported (from WPF to JS) and created new applications in web. At this moment I'd always prefer JS over WPF, because it's MUCH easier to develop (mostly because there are much more third party libraries for all purposes). Not to mention WPF is not cross platform and only works on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ElectronJS https://www.electronjs.org
With this you can create Desktop app with JS for UI.
With this you can create one UI and use it for desktop and Web app.